# Kerberos constrained delegation not working

Tags: active-directory, iis, sql, delegation

I have a typical double hop scenario, User ->IIS->SQL.

I am using IIS 7.5, which is using Kernal Model Authentication, so I am setting up the IIS server account for delegation.

If I set this to "Trust this computer for delegation to any service"
[image]

Then it works fine. However, I would like to use constrained delegation to work. I have setup SPN's for the SQL server (for both SQLServer and SQLServer.domain.com) and tested the setup using [DelegConfig](http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2009/04/22/delegconfig-v2-beta.aspx), which says it is fine, but it does not work.

Does anyone know of a way to see what SPN is being used when I run this with Unconstrained delegation, so I can set this up for constrained? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would enable Kerberos logging on the IIS machine.  This surfaces a lot of helpful information, including SPN's and related errors.  Takes effect without a restart on Windows Server 2008.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters]
"LogLevel"=dword:00000001
```

NetMon may also show SPN's.

Are the IIS and SQL servers in the same AD Domain?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same domain. Will check logging now.

Comment: I would second the NETMON or WireShark as you can specifically target the Kerberos protocol packets using in-built display filter and get all the SPN and whether they succeed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the SPNs you set for SQL? Have you confirmed they're set on the computer account (if SQL is running as Network Service/Local System) or the service account otherwise?